# Why am i getting null as xml response from rest template call in springboot?

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xml-parsing, resttemplate

> I am trying to call another uri using rest template but the response 
>   I am getting is null.Please help me out. On using postman I am getting
>   complete xml response as below.

```
<ParentContest>
    <CONTEST identifier="refer">
        <contest_id>10</contest_id>
        <Alias></Alias>
        <contest_desc></contest_desc>
        <start_date>2019-11-11 00:00:00</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-12-29 23:59:59</end_date>
        <creation_date>2019-11-29 00:00:00</creation_date>
        <modification_date>2019-11-29 00:00:00</modification_date>
        <max_questions>100</max_questions>
        <max_question_per_day>100</max_question_per_day>
        <isactive>true</isactive>
        <max_skip_question_counter></max_skip_question_counter>
        <questions_block_duration></questions_block_duration>
        <category>football</category>
    </CONTEST>
    <CONTEST identifier="test">
        <contest_id>2</contest_id>
        <Alias></Alias>
        <contest_desc></contest_desc>
        <start_date>2019-11-29 00:00:00</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-12-20 23:59:59</end_date>
        <creation_date>2019-11-29 00:00:00</creation_date>
        <modification_date>2019-11-29 00:00:00</modification_date>
        <max_questions>100</max_questions>
        <max_question_per_day>100</max_question_per_day>
        <isactive>true</isactive>
        <max_skip_question_counter></max_skip_question_counter>
        <questions_block_duration></questions_block_duration>
        <category>cricket</category>
    </CONTEST>
</ParentContest>
```

> The uri that is being passes in rest call is also correct(I printed
>   the uri on console).
>
> But when I am calling it through rest template as below :

```
public ResponseEntity<ParentContest> getQuizFromContestEngine(String operator,String circle) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String url = targetUrl;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
    headers.set("operator",operator);
    headers.set("circle",circle);

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("operator", operator)
            .queryParam("circle", circle);

    logger.info(builder.toUriString());

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    ResponseEntity<ParentContest> response = null;
    try {

    response = restTemplate.exchange(
            url, 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            entity, 
            ParentContest.class);


    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception :::",e);
    }
    //logger.info(response.getBody().getContest().get(0).toString());
    return response;}
```

I am getting below output:

`<ParentContest/>`

The Pojo are as below :

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="ParentContest")
public class ParentContest{



    @XmlElement(name = "CONTEST")
    private List<CONTEST> contest;

    public List<CONTEST> getContest() {
        return contest;
    }

    public void setContest(List<CONTEST> contest) {
        this.contest = contest;
    }




}
```

/

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement(name="CONTEST")
public class CONTEST {


    @XmlAttribute(name = "identifier")
    private String identifier; 

    @XmlElement(name = "contest_id")
    private long contestId;

    @XmlElement(name = "Alias")
    private String alias;

    @XmlElement(name = "contest_desc")
    private String contestDesc;

    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    private String startDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    private String endDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "creation_date")
    private String creationDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "modification_date")
    private String modificationDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "max_questions")
    private String maxQuestions;

    @XmlElement(name = "max_question_per_day")
    private String maxQuesPerDay;

    @XmlElement(name = "max_skip_question_counter")
    private String maxSkipQuestionCounter;

    @XmlElement(name = "questions_block_duration")
    private String questionsBlockDuration;

    @XmlElement(name = "isactive")
    private String isActive;

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }



    public long getContestId() {
        return contestId;
    }

    public void setContestId(long contestId) {
        this.contestId = contestId;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getContestDesc() {
        return contestDesc;
    }

    public void setContestDesc(String contestDesc) {
        this.contestDesc = contestDesc;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getModificationDate() {
        return modificationDate;
    }

    public void setModificationDate(String modificationDate) {
        this.modificationDate = modificationDate;
    }

    public String getMaxQuestions() {
        return maxQuestions;
    }

    public void setMaxQuestions(String maxQuestions) {
        this.maxQuestions = maxQuestions;
    }

    public String getMaxQuesPerDay() {
        return maxQuesPerDay;
    }

    public void setMaxQuesPerDay(String maxQuesPerDay) {
        this.maxQuesPerDay = maxQuesPerDay;
    }

    public String getMaxSkipQuestionCounter() {
        return maxSkipQuestionCounter;
    }

    public void setMaxSkipQuestionCounter(String maxSkipQuestionCounter) {
        this.maxSkipQuestionCounter = maxSkipQuestionCounter;
    }

    public String getQuestionsBlockDuration() {
        return questionsBlockDuration;
    }

    public void setQuestionsBlockDuration(String questionsBlockDuration) {
        this.questionsBlockDuration = questionsBlockDuration;
    }

    public String getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(String isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

}
`
```

Below is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>one97.net</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dream11Fantacy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Dream11Fantacy</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> Since no exception is being thrown from response the problem seemed in
>   conversion from xml response using pojo mapping. I tried mapping pojo
>   with javax.xml.bind.annotation and
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation, but the output
>   remained the same.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check the response status before accessing the body.
My guess is the HTTP status is not 2xx.

Post the actual response with the status.

Comment: response was 200 on postman and it took a lot of time around 20-25 second to generate one line output.

Comment: i found that one parameter of xml which is not in pojo  , category. i will check tomorrow ,but will this be tge cause of problem